# Why does global supersymmetry commute with gauge transformations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, gauge-theory, non-perturbative

In particular, I would like to understand the following quotation from a paper by Witten: [Nucl.Phys. B188 (1981) 513](http://inspirehep.net/record/10634) (p. 515 at the top) His statement:

> This is so because in global supersymmetry the superalgebras always commute with gauge symmetries; the commutator, if not zero, would be a supersymmetry transformation depending on the infinite number of parameters of the gauge symmetry, so would have to be local supersymmetry.

Could someone please explain the last statement about the infinite number of parameters in a more explicit way?

Comment: For each space-time point $x$ , you have different possible parameters $\phi^a(x)$ of the gauge symmetry which depend on this space-time point : $\psi(x) \to e^{i\phi^a(x) T_a}\psi(x)$. So, for the whole space-time, this gives an infinite number of parameters.

Comment: So, what happens exactly, if supersymmetry does not commute with gauge transformations?

Comment: I think that the rough idea, is that the commutators of the supersymmetric charges $Q_\alpha, \bar Q_\dot\alpha$, with the gauge parameters $\phi_a(x)$ may be written $C_{\alpha a} (x), C_{\dot\alpha a} (x)$, so these commutators, if not null, would have a supersymmetric charge indice ($\alpha , \dot\alpha $), and they depend on $x$, so they could represent some local supersymmetry.

Comment: Is it always true that $C_{\alpha a}(x)=[Q_\alpha,\phi_a(x)]$ always satisfy the the supersymmetry algebra $\{C_{\alpha a},{\bar C}_{\dot\beta b}\}=2\gamma^\mu_{\alpha\dot\beta}K_{ab}P_\mu$? And what would that $K_{ab}$ be? Is it a good superalgebra with $K_{ab}$ included?

Comment: Good question .... In fact, local supersymmetry is supergravity, so I would say that this has to be studied in this frame (with  spins $2,3/2$, etc...).

Comment: I don't know much about supergravity. My understanding of it was that it is an (extended) supersymmetry which accomodates spin-2 states. So still the same algebra

Comment: What's exactly incomprehensible about Witten's explanation? He's just saying that the commutator of the SUSY generators with infinitely many (point-based) generators of the gauge symmetry, if nonzero, would be a collection of infinitely many Grassmann-odd i.e. fermionic generators, so they would form a local supersymmetry algebra. That's only possible in supergravity because the usual anticommutator of SUSies has to be local, too, so the momentum is local which means that diffeomorphisms belong to the group of local gauge generators. SUGRA.

Comment: Thank you Luboš. The only thing I didn't understand was which kind of algebra these new local operators form. I know how the (anit-) commutators of the usual global supersymmetry look like, but I don't see which (anti-) commutators correspond to the local operators. In particular, since I'm not very familiar with SUGRA, I'm not sure which algebra is typical so I can really see these local operators form the algebra of supergravity. Or do we call any algebra generated by fermionic operators a SUGRA algebra?